# How to convert this code to an asynchronous implementation?

Tags: c#, list, asynchronous, task

Yesterday I wrote an interview test and this question being one of them.
I am not sure how to solve this.
If possible, please would you explain this code?

Given the following interface:

```
public interface ISearch
{
    List<Person> Search(string filter);
    Task<List<Person>> SearchAsync(string filter);
}
```

Convert the following code to an asynchronous implementation:

```
public List<Person> SearchPersons(ISearch searcher, string filter)
{
    return searcher.Search(filter);
}
```

Comment: I recommend reading up on the basics of asynchronous programming with `Task` and `async`/`await`. If you know these things the exercise is trivial; if you don't there's no way you could possibly complete it successfully. As such it's a pretty good question on basic knowledge.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async

Comment: `SearchPersons` seems like such a pointless method, even as an interview question. After all, you have to pass `ISearch` and `filter` to it, so why wouldn't you just call the `Search` method directly?

Comment: For those that can answer the question, I would appreciate it dearly.

Comment: Hint: Look at this: `Task<List<Person>>` in the interface.

Comment: The real point is that you must be able to answer the question yourself, and you should be able to after having read up on `Task`. Being able to regurgitate what someone plastered on the internet is pointless in this case, because you still wouldn't understand how asynchronous programming works, and you'd probably fail the second question they'd ask about it. It's not about getting the right answer in this case.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Jeroen wasn't saying that though (unless a comment has been deleted). Admittedly the answer here is simple, but without studying async programming in general, it will be a useless nugget of information if OP can't then answer the follow-up interview questions because they still won't get the job. That's why I linked the documentation as a starting point for OP learning about this stuff so that OP can understand it.

Answer (score 2):

if you only care about the answer here it is:

```
public async Task<List<Person>> SearchPersonAsync(ISearch searcher, string filter)
{
    return await searcher.SearchAsync(filter);
}
```

or as comment from [@DiplomacyNotWar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3181933/diplomacynotwar) stated just return directly since there is no other logic besides pasing the filter:

`var result = await searcher.SearchAsync(filter);`

However, if you're not sure what async/await is about, it wouldn't help you at all and as comments stated even though answer is really basic and simple it won't get you anywhere.
It's better to start from learning what's the point of wrapping this logic into async in the first place. General promise is that it's not going to be blocking main thread, however topic is really broad. Here are some resources that might help you understand what's going on behind the scenes:

- [Asynchronous programming from MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async)
- [Begginer friendly video tutorial by  IAmTimCorey](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2moh18sh5p4)
- [Written tutorial step by step by  Vivek Kumar](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/async-and-await-in-c-sharp/)

Comment: Thank you @xdjiijii, I do appreciate your help and the resources, I will definitely check up on them. I gave my answer in but I wasn't sure if my answer was right or not. One down side to taking the online test, you don't know where you went wrong and if the answer is wrong.